# Customize ListView in android with various element

Tags: android, listview

http://www.mediafire.com/?qy9zofrc07op64a this is my screeshoot . I dont have enough reputation for uploading picture

I have a trouble with this  design . Follow my screenshot above , It has various element need to add to a listview's row . Trouble with mixing relativelayout and linear layout . Any help would be appropriate .

Comment: What is exactly wrong? Your question is not very clear.

Comment: Check what have you tried so far. http://stackoverflow.com/help

Comment: what is the problem you are facing. post your code so things can be clear.

Comment: As i said , i need some help to create a layout with various element like my screenshoot . I tried but it's very hard to mix relative layout and linnear layout . Should I create each element with a layout .  I need some hint plz

Answer (score 0):

You should start with these tutorial 
http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/
http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-listview-example/

You can mix any layout you want to.

You are trying to create your own **custom listview**.Youll need to inflate  your layout into the Listview

Comment: You can also use your custom layout in the .xml layout file. You just need to write the whole class name.

Comment: I tried google and follow with those tutorial , but the layout in that tutorial doesnt not have á many element as mine . So when i add some element . It become hard to arrange them.

Comment: @user2780771 i think you are using relative layout , use linear layout http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-linearlayout-example/